# Floating div covers the next div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to position a `<div>` on a line, and then another `<div>` afterward.

I set the first `<div>` to float left, and then put in the next one.

However, the first div is covering the second one. It's not positioning the second one after the first (as I expected) - it's starting it from the same place.

Here's the code (on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LcrA9/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}
#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;    
}
#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float the second div, or put a `margin-left` equal to the first div's width:

[Floating JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/LcrA9/4/):

```
#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

[Margin-left JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/LcrA9/5/)

```
#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**@PlantTheIdea's** suggestion to use `display: inline-block` is sound. This question *does* have a purpose though: when you want the second div to consume the remaining space (and don't want to use `display: table` e.g.)

[Here's an example of that too](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/LcrA9/7/):

```
#container {
    height: 500px;
    clear: both;
}

#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;    
}

#two {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: agreed, that would be one case to possibly use floats (I'd still arge for `display:table-cell;`, but if you need to support IE7 for some reason), however the widths are preset in this case. and @Zafar that is eliminated if you read my answer by removing the whitespace between the `div`s.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea even in my work we've dropped IE7 support. I fought it for a long time! I try to avoid referencing tables anywhere unless I really want to show tabular data. It's probably prejudice from the "lets do everything tables" days.

Comment: `display:table;` is **not** the same thing as HTML tables => http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

Comment: Hah, no I am 100% aware, hence "It's probably just prejudice"

Answer (score 1):

You need to ditch the floats, and discover `display:inline-block;` my friend!

Your HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">
    </div><div id="two">
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}

#one,#two {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;

    /* Old IE */
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}

#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;    
}

#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Here is an updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrA9/2/)

The reason I eliminated the space between the two `div`s is because if there were any space, `inline-block` would put a 4px margin between them. The Old IE pieces are for IE7 and below.

Comment: `display: inline-block;` adds some unnecessary space between divs.

Comment: @Zafar - if you read my answer, you'll see I called that out and eliminated it by removing the whitespace between the `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need `float:left` on both `div`s

```
#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;    
}
#two {
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrA9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by making the second div float as well:

```
#two {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float left the next one too!!

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
}
#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;    
}
#two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another "float:left" value on second div.

```
#one {
width: 100px;
height: 500px;
float: left;
background-color: green;
```

}

```
#two {
width: 200px;
height: 500px;
background-color: blue;
float:left;
margin-left:20px
```

}

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/LcrA9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Set The `#two` Div to `float:left` as well.